# Ruby / Sinatra - POST data without form

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra

I have a button which is a link. When a user clicks on that link, I want to do a POST to another route which processes this click. Can I do it somehow without using a `<form>`? That means, just clicking on the link and the link is not the submit button of a form.

```
<a href="/buyitem/"><button class="btn btn-info small">Buy Item</button></a>
```

I know that it would be possible with AJAX, but I wonder if there is another way.

AJAX-way:

```
$.post('/buyitem', { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, function(result) {
    alert('successfully posted key1=value1&key2=value2');
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the ajax-post? This is the way to go.

Comment: well, I just wondered if there is another way :)

Comment: Well, I don't know of one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, there's no way of telling an html link without js to got down the post route. Tried to figure out the same for `DELETE` links.